# IF/Else Matching First Character of String, ICD-10 Diagnosis Codes

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro which takes an ICD code and translate the code into one of about 16 diagnosis categories. it does this by first recognizing whether the code is ICD 9 or 10 (this part works), removing leading zeros (this works), removing anything after a decimal (this works) and then using If statements to determine which category this code falls into (works for ICD9 but not ICD10)

ICD-10 codes are in the format [letter][###].[##] such as 'K50.814'. Worksheet functions transform this to 'K50' (the general group). My macro accepts 'K50'.

An example of the error:

Input: R57

Output: #Value

Debugging:

Debug.Print (strDxLetter): R

Debug.Print VarType(strDxLetter): 8

Debug.Print (intDxCode): 57

```
Function DxGroup2(Diagnosis As Variant)
'Diagnosis as variant because ICD9 uses only numbers whereas ICD10 starts with letter followed by numbers

Dim strDxLetter As String
'Variable will be used to store the first letter of the icd10 dx
Dim intDxCode As Integer


'Here there are normally if statements for ICD9 codes. This part works fine

'If not ICD 9 then the coding method used must have been ICD 10
    Else
        'Get the first character of the ICD code which is the diagnosis group letter
        strDxLetter = Left(Diagnosis, 1)

        'Get the rest of the ICD code which was converted to an integer in the worksheet
        intDxCode = Mid(Diagnosis, 2, Len(Diagnosis))

'Here is where I tried error testing. The first letter is being returned accurately, the data type is string for the letter, and the code is being returned correctly 

        Debug.Print (strDxLetter)
        Debug.Print VarType(strDxLetter)
        Debug.Print (intDxCode)

    'First match up the letter code with the diagnosis group
    If strDxLetter = "A" Or "B" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Infectious and Parasitic Disease"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "C" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Neoplasms"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "D" Then
        If intDxCode >= 0 And intDxCode <= 9 Then
            DxGroup2 = "Neoplasms"
        ElseIf intDxCode >= 50 And intDxCode <= 89 Then
            DxGroup2 = "Blood and Blood-Forming Organs"
        Else
            DxGroup2 = "Manually lookup this code"
        End If
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "E" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Endocrine, Nutritional, Metabolic, Immunity"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "F" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Mental Disorders, Don't count this patient"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "G" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Nervous System and Sense Organs"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "H" Then
        If intDxCode > 0 And intDxCode <= 59 Then
            DxGroup2 = "Disease of eye and adnexa"
        ElseIf intDxCode > 59 And intDxCode <= 95 Then
            DxGroup2 = "Diseaase of the ear and mastoid"
        Else
            DxGroup2 = "Manually look up this code"
        End If
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "I" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Circulatory System"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "J" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Respiratory System"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "K" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Digestive System"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "L" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Skin and Subcutaneous Tissue"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "M" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Musculoskeletal System and Connective Tissue"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "N" Then
         DxGroup2 = "Genitourinary System"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "O" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Pregnancy, Childbirth, and the Puerperium"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "P" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Conditions Originating in the Perinatal Period"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "Q" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Congenital Malformations, chromosomal abnormalities"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "R" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Nonspecific Abnormal Findings"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "S" Or strDxLetter = "T" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Injury and Poisoning"
    ElseIf strDxLetter = "V" Or strDxLetter = "W" Or strDxLetter = "X" Or strDxLetter = "Y" Then
        DxGroup2 = "Ill-Defined and Unknown Causes of Morbidity and Mortality"
    Else
        DxGroup2 = "Supplemental"
    End If
End If
Debug.Print DxGroup2
End Function
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `case` statements?

Comment: Call your function from a Test Sub or from the Immediate pane in the VB editor: that will show you the problem

Comment: @findwindow I was not familiar with the `case` statement but I looked it up and think it will be more suitable. I will try that and use Tim's advice when I am at work tomorrow and see if that fixes the problem and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue here:

```
If strDxLetter = "A" Or "B" Then
```

should be

```
If strDxLetter = "A" Or strDxLetter = "B" Then
```